# Joining two tables KDB with different row count

Tags: kdb

Having issues joining two below tables when they have a different count

```
t1:flip (`sym`d2)!(`AUDUSD`AUDUSD`AUDUSD`EURCH`EURCHF`EURCHF;9241.982 1646.12 0.214144 -5298.589 489.61 0.005779397)

t2:flip (`sym`d3)!(`AUDUSD`AUDUSD`AUDUSD`EURCH`EURCHF`EURCHF;21322.79 1467.17 0.2878328 -6447.091 487.66 0.00159537)

t3:-1_t2
```

With the above I can join the tables using t1,'t2 however I am getting length error on t1,'t3.

How can I join t1 and t3 together? I want to keep all the rows from t1 and fill t3 with null

desired result of joining t1 and t3 is the below

```
flip (`sym`d2`d3)!(`AUDUSD`AUDUSD`AUDUSD`EURCH`EURCHF`EURCHF;9241.982 1646.12 0.214144 -5298.589 489.61 0.005779397;21322.79 1467.17 0.2878328 -6447.091 487.66 0n)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since `sym` values in your tables are not unique it's not clear which criteria you want your join to use. It'd be easier to answer your question if you could show what the result should be.

Comment: Hi Igor, I am trying to get the result of joining t1 and t3 to look like the below ```flip (`sym`d2`d3)!(`AUDUSD`AUDUSD`AUDUSD`EURCH`EURCHF`EURCHF;9241.982 1646.12 0.214144 -5298.589 489.61 0.005779397;21322.79 1467.17 0.2878328 -6447.091 487.66 0n)```

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution but it assumes that if there are missing values they are always at the end and the first N values in t2 must be matched with the first N values with t1.

```
q)f:{[t1;t2]{x[0]lj`i xkey x 1}![;();0b;enlist[`i]!enlist`i]each(t1;t2)}
q)
q)f[t1;t2]
sym    d2          i d3
-------------------------------
AUDUSD 9241.982    0 21322.79
AUDUSD 1646.12     1 1467.17
AUDUSD 0.214144    2 0.2878328
EURCH  -5298.589   3 -6447.091
EURCHF 489.61      4 487.66
EURCHF 0.005779397 5 0.00159537
q)f[t1;t3]
sym    d2          i d3
------------------------------
AUDUSD 9241.982    0 21322.79
AUDUSD 1646.12     1 1467.17
AUDUSD 0.214144    2 0.2878328
EURCH  -5298.589   3 -6447.091
EURCHF 489.61      4 487.66
EURCHF 0.005779397 5
```

All kdb tables have an internal i (row index) column. I don't think you can directly use this for a join without updating your table but maybe someone else knows how that is possible. Delete i column too if you want.

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to this specific problem, you could extract the column of data you want from t3, append null values to it, and update t1 with the new column. So:

```
q)update d3: ((exec d3 from t3),0n) from t1
sym    d2          d3
----------------------------
AUDUSD 9241.982    21322.79
AUDUSD 1646.12     1467.17
AUDUSD 0.214144    0.2878328
EURCH  -5298.589   -6447.091
EURCHF 489.61      487.66
EURCHF 0.005779397
```

Ordinarily, you can get around joining tables of different lengths by using left-join (lj), but that won't work in this case because lj requires a key to join on, and there is no unique identifier for your rows that would be suitable...

```
q)t1 lj 1!t3
sym    d2          d3
----------------------------
AUDUSD 9241.982    21322.79
AUDUSD 1646.12     21322.79
AUDUSD 0.214144    21322.79
EURCH  -5298.589   -6447.091
EURCHF 489.61      487.66
EURCHF 0.005779397 487.66
```

Here you can see that the values in d3 are repeating based on the value of the sym column.
Note: n!t3 makes t3 a keyed table using the first n columns (in this example, just sym), which is necessary as lj requires a keyed table as it's right argument.